# Rails 3 Creating an Object in a Foreign Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have a Transaction object and want to:

1. Check if a Cart session exists.
2. If yes, associate the Transaction with that Cart's ID from the session.
3. If no, create a new Cart object and assign its ID to a session variable.

The relationship is:

```
Cart has_many Transactions
Transaction belongs_to Cart
```

My question is: How do you / What is the best way to create a Cart object and associated session from within the Transaction controller?

I tried something like this in the Transaction new action:

```
@cart = Cart.new
```

And, this in the Transaction create action:

```
@cart = Cart.new(params[:cart])
session[:cart] = @cart.id
```

But, that doesn't create a session or Cart object. And, when searching Google I wasn't able to find documentation on this type of thing. Does anyone know how it is done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cart.new
```

... will only instantiate a new Cart but will not **persist** it into the database. The Cart object needs to be stored in the database if it is to be used across requests.

Use this to persist the Cart object:

```
Cart.create(params[:cart])
```

or

```
@cart.save!
```

For this:

```
session[:cart] = @cart.id
```

... you've done the right thing by storing the ID in the session :) But note that you need to fetch this again on every request. So you could add a helper in your `application_controller.rb` with something like:

```
def current_cart
  Cart.find_by_id(session[:cart])
end
```

.... which could return a `nil` cart.

Comment: I had one follow-on question here: I tried adding a the customer_id to the Cart object using the session[:customer_id] (which exists), but it doesn't work when I do @cart.customer_id = session[:customer_id]. When using the Cart.create method, is there a different way that you add information to populate fields within the controller? Thanks again for any assistance!

Comment: You need to do save the cart object after you assign the customer_id to it: `@cart.save`. When using `Cart.create` you can provide a hash of parameters, one of which is `:customer_id`, or you can just assign the customer ID to the object after it has been created and then save it again.

Comment: On another note, try to avoid relying on the session for storing state. This can be quite fragile (for example, if the user delete's their cookies). But it seems that for what you are doing it's OK.

Comment: One more thing :) - if you are using a good authentication library (Devise, Clearance, Authlogic, etc) you shouldn't need to store the customer_id in the session, as the library will make available a `current_user` object for you.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I'll try the `@cart.save` after assigning the customer_id. I'm trying to develop a complete application without plugins to learn the framework. So, the authentication (which is done) and the shopping cart (in the works) are done by hand. But don't worry, this isn't going into production or anything yet- more of a functional demo at this stage :)